# How do I add authentication/security to access HBase using happybase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hbase, thrift, happybase

I'm using happybase to access HBase. However, the only parameter I need is the host name. How does Thrift work without authentication? How do I add security to my code?

Answer (score 0):

thrift servers are generally only run in a trusted network. that said, thrift can run over ssl but support in happybase is limited because no one stepped up to properly design and implement an api for it. feel free to contribute.